# NSView to PDF and PNG: Why is the outcome so different?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, draw, nsview

I am trying to safe an `NSView` to an PNG. 
I start with the `NSView` and then call `dataWithPDF` or `cacheDisplay` for PNG. The code to do both looks like this.

```
guard view.lockFocusIfCanDraw() else {
    assert (false)
    return
}
let pdfData = view.dataWithPDF(inside: rect)
guard let imgData = view.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: rect) else {
    assert(false)
}
view.cacheDisplay(in: rect, to: imgData)
view.unlockFocus()
try pdfData.write(to: pdfName, options: .atomic)
let pngData = imgData.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
try pngData!.write(to: pngName, options: .atomic)
```

So far, so good. However, this is the different outcome. 
PDF (correct!)
[image: correct PDF output]
And this is the PNG output. As one can see, the subviews aren't included. The arrows are drawn as part of `view`
[image]

Why is the outcome so different?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Thanks to "View Debugging" did I see that the subviews use a layer (`self.wantsLayer = true`). And layers are not finding their way into the PNG, but into the PDF. Not sure whether this is a bug or a feature. However, now I can fix the PNG output.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the outcome so different?

Trying your code using a different (I obviously don't have your view) view with subviews works as expected and the PNG is fine. So it has to be something to do with your views, but I can make no suggestion as to what. However...

As you've got valid PDF data you can generate your PNG from that using something like:

```
let captured = NSImage(data:pdfData)
let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(data:(captured?.tiffRepresentation)!)
let pngData = rep?.representation(using: NSPNGFileType, properties:[:])
```

*(that is Swift 3, hence `NSPNGFileType` rather than `.png`)*

This of course doesn't solve whatever problem you have, it avoids it :-) You should really figure out why your views are failing and treat this as a temporary band aid (assuming it works for you...).

HTH

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. However, `captured.tiffRepresentation` throws an error.

Comment: Not sure yet what error it is. Didn’t have the time to understand the issue. Will come back with details. Thanks again

Comment: Curious... Have you tried opening the PDF in Preview and saving it out as a PNG? I can't think offhand why it would fail, but maybe worth checking. (Of course if it does work in your code you could write the PDF to a temp file, read it back in, convert to PNG as above... but that goes way beyond a band-aid into full body cast territory! )

Comment: I can save in Preview to PNG. No issue. But I cannot identify the error. It is a `__cxa_throw`, triggered in `[NSImage TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:factor:]:` but no further information for me to gather. I might not know enough about lldb debugging.

Comment: The PDF and PNG/TIFF codepaths are probably very different, with the former being able to record drawing instructions earlier in the process and the latter working on the resultant bits. It looks like your sub views may all be of the same kind, you can try removing all but one and see if that works. If it does try binary search removing half the sub views and keep halving until you find the culprit(s). Then you need to figure out what these are doing which is causing the issue. Good hunting!

Comment: good thinking again. I tried different node shapes, down to a simple text. I believe that in spite of the description the subviews are simply not drawn. I further believe that it worked previously, hence I suspect an cocoa bug in the latest version. (I found another bug in core data for macOS introduced in high Sierra, so I might be too narrowed in my thinking)

Comment: hmmm. Did a small test project. Cannot replicate the issue. Will need to search.

Comment: I found it! Wrote it as another answer. It was the wantsLayer! Thanks again!